# TeamCity Professional License

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm considering TeamCity for CI and not sure whether I can use Professional License (which is free) for commercial application?

From their license page https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/ , seem like the Professional License only restricted in number of build configuration and build agents, doesn't mention anything about commercial usage.

In their FAQ https://sales.jetbrains.com/hc/en-gb, they are talking about commercial license and personal license, not mentioning professional license and enterprise license, which makes me even more confused. Is the FAQ page outdated?

My application is .NET application, hosted in Github (private). We intend to setup TeamCity in AWS as build server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the licensing (section 4b: https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/license.html), there is no restriction for corporations.

Note: In my division we currently use the free version, and we didn't find any difficulties. We are still planning to upgrade soon because of the limited build configurations.

Answer (score 4):

TeamCity can be used for commercial purposes, but is restricted to 20 build configurations and 3 build agents. If you want to use more build configurations or agents, then you need to upgrade to a paid licence.

However, if you just need additional build agents, these can be bought separately.

Answer (score 3):

From TeamCity 2017.2 onwards, the professional version (free) includes 100 build configurations, which is a significant increase on the previous versions that were limited to 20. It still has a limit of 3 build agents.
Further info here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Licensing+Policy

Comment: Thanks for such valuable info about increasing of configurations number.